# css bootstrap center text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hellooo guys,

i'm trying to center my text with bootstrap, but nothing happens. What's wrong?

```
<footer class="row p-1 mt-3 bg-primary text-white">
    <p class="text-center">footer</p>
</footer>
```

thanks, your ramen

Comment: your text centered. bootstrap loading? or some other styles above occurs this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions here

### Solution 1

i dont see a benefit here for using **row** , so you can remove it unless you have **col-*** inside your footer

```
 <footer class="p-1 mt-3 bg-primary text-white">
            <p class="text-center">footer</p>
     </footer>
```

### Solution 2

or if you want to keep row just add this class to your row justify-content-center

```
<footer class="row p-1 mt-3 bg-primary text-white justify-content-center">
        <p class="text-center">footer</p>
 </footer>
```

### Solution 3

Insert a new element , add col-12 to it

```
 <footer class="row p-1 mt-3 bg-primary text-white ">
             <div class="col-12">
                 <p class="text-center">footer</p>
             </div>
     </footer>
```